What are good ways to make a forced line break within a table cell while maintaining proper formatting?
I looked into some of the different solutions provided in the following thread on how to make forced line breaks within a table cell:
How to add a forced line break inside a table cell
Based on that, I then compiled a table consisting of some of the suggested line break methods to see how they interact with how I've listed the formatting of my tables in the preamble:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

% Must have features for my tables

\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

% ________________________________

\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 
% Package for \strutlongstacks{T} forced linebreak method

\usepackage{makecell}
% Package for \makecell forced linebreak method

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

    \centering
    \strutlongstacks{T}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|m{3cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Calender for the rest of the year} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Homework} & \textbf{Goal}  \\
        \hline
        Week 1 & Homework 1 and 2 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Goal for 1 is to... \\ Goal for 2 is to... \end{tabular} \\ % Text exceeds cell when limit is reached
        \hline
        Week 2 & Homework 3 and 4 & \vtop{\hbox{\strut Goal for 3 is to...}\hbox{\strut Goal for 4 is to...}} \\ % Force elongates cell on itself when limit is exceeded
        \hline
        Week 3 & Homework 5 and 6 & \Centerstack{Goal for 5 is to... \\ Goal for 6 is to...} \\ % Text exceeds cell when limit is reached
        \hline
        Week 4 & Homework 7 and 8 & \begin{flushleft} Goal for 7 is to... \\ Goal for 8 is to... \end{flushleft} \\ % Works for long text, too, only for column types of "|m{}|", though, not for regular "|c|"
        \hline
        Week 5 & Homework 9 and 10 & \parbox{3cm}{Goal for 9 is to... \\ Goal for 10 is to...} \\ % Works but completely ignores the \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} in the preamble
        \hline
        Week 6 & Homework 11 and 12 & \makecell{Goal for 11 is to... \\ Goal for 12 is to...} \\ % Text exceeds cell when limit is reached
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}

You can see here how it looks on the output side:

I like how goal 1 and 2 is displayed and compliments my settings in the preamble, and thus I'd ideally like if it could be modified such that when I'm using m{3cm} in the third column that the second column is still centered like for homework 7 and 8 AND also makes auto line breaks when the text exceeds the limits provided to the cell.
If you guys can think of any ways to optimize any of these to be properly formatted or come up with new creative ways which do, it'd be greatly appreciated if you share them in here:)

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be marked as a code sample.

Doesn't seem tedious to me at all:) I just created an account on here today, and so I'd also appreciate all of the feedback I could get for how to optimize my questions in here to be as convenient as possible for people willing to help - Thank you very much! I've now indented all of the lines by 4 spaces and included my entire document in it. Also, I initially wrote the "%" operator for extra clarification of the code where I thought needed. Could you re-check if the information I've provided now is sufficient to solve the task?

I don't think you need anything fancy… Apart for \tabularnewline in order to end rows, because of \\ in the last column.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|>{\raggedright}m{5cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Calendar for the rest of the year} \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Date} & \textbf{Homework} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Goal}}  \tabularnewline
\hline
Week 1 & Homework 1 and 2 &
  Goal for 1 is to... lot of things that take many lines \\[6pt]
  Goal for 2 is to... lot of things that take many lines \tabularnewline
\hline
Week 2 & Homework 3 and 4 &
  Goal for 3 is to... lot of things that take many lines \\[6pt]
  Goal for 4 is to... lot of things that take many lines \tabularnewline
\hline
Week 3 & Homework 5 and 6 &
  Goal for 5 is to... lot of things that take many lines \\[6pt]
  Goal for 6 is to... lot of things that take many lines
  Goal for 1 is to... \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}

\end{table}

\end{document}


Alternative layout:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}cc>{\raggedright}p{5cm}@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Calendar for the rest of the year} \tabularnewline
\midrule
\textbf{Date} & \textbf{Homework} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Goal}}  \tabularnewline
\midrule
Week 1 & Homework 1 and 2 &
  Goal for 1 is to... lot of things that take many lines \\[6pt]
  Goal for 2 is to... lot of things that take many lines \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
Week 2 & Homework 3 and 4 &
  Goal for 3 is to... lot of things that take many lines \\[6pt]
  Goal for 4 is to... lot of things that take many lines \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
Week 3 & Homework 5 and 6 &
  Goal for 5 is to... lot of things that take many lines \\[6pt]
  Goal for 6 is to... lot of things that take many lines
  Goal for 1 is to... \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}

\end{table}

\end{document}



I didn't know \tabularnewline. I link this answer for people, like me, who needs some explanations.

Omg, tysm! It's an easy and intuitive solution to my problem which also allows you to control another variable that I didn't even think of: the vertical space between the '\' -command to really make the formatting look extra crisp. I also remember you were the author of one of the solutions in the original thread which I included:) @jlab ty for also providing additional information to understand the technical implications of each command!

As I understand your problem is to get a fixed size multi-lines column, vertically centered.
You can use fixed sizes in \makecell. Example:
\makecell[c{p{3cm}}]{Goal for 1 is to... \\ Goal for 2 is to...}

will create a vertically centered cell, with a fixed width of 3cm. In your case, since the width is set in column specification, replace 3cm with \hsize (it will take the with of the column). But to get a correct vertical position, you must let \makecell handle it and use p{3cm} instead of m{3cm} in the column specification.
Add also
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\def\arraytretch{1.5}}%

if you want larger spaces inside \makecell.
Full example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

% Must have features for my tables

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\def\arraytretch{1.5}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Calender for the rest of the year}                                 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Date}   & \textbf{Homework} & \textbf{Goal}                                                                \\
    \hline
    \hline
    Week 1 & Homework 1 and 2
           & \makecell[c{p{\hsize}}]{Goal for 1 is to... lot of things that take many lines \\
             Goal for 2 is to... lot of things that take many lines}                        \\
    \hline
    Week 2 & Homework 3 and 4
           & \makecell[c{p{\hsize}}]{Goal for 3 is to... lot of things that take many lines \\
             Goal for 4 is to... lot of things that take many lines}                        \\
    \hline
    Week 3 & Homework 5 and 6
           & \makecell[c{p{\hsize}}]{Goal for 5 is to... lot of things that take many lines \\
             Goal for 6 is to... lot of things that take many lines}                                     \\
     \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{With \textsf{makecell}}
  \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Anyway, there is now the tabularray package, which provides many customisations for tables through a modern key-value interface and replicates the functionalities of classic table packages. With tabularray, a vertically centered columns of 3cm width is set with Q[3cm,m] (Q is the columns specifier used by tabularray) and multi-lines cell are simply obtained with braces:
Week 1 & Homework 1 and 2  & {Goal for 1 is to...\\  Goal for 2 is to...} \\

Example (see how its clearer, with a separation between formatting and content):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

% Must have features for my tables

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}
    {
      colspec={ | Q[c,m] | Q[c,m] | Q[3cm,m] |},
      hline{1-Z} = {1}{-}{0.5mm, solid},
      hline{3} = {2}{-}{0.5mm, solid},
      vlines={0.5mm},
      row{2} = {font=\bfseries},
      colsep=18pt,
      stretch=1.5,
    }
    \SetCell[c=3]{c} Calender for the rest of the year
    \\
    Date   & Homework & Goal
    \\
    Week 1 & Homework 1 and 2
    & {Goal for 1 is to... lot of things that take many lines \\[6pt]
      Goal for 2 is to... lot of things that take many lines}
    \\
    Week 2 & Homework 3 and 4
    & {Goal for 3 is to... lot of things that take many lines \\[6pt]
      Goal for 4 is to... lot of things that take many lines}
    \\
    Week 3 & Homework 5 and 6
    & {Goal for 5 is to... lot of things that take many lines   \\[6pt]
      Goal for 6 is to... lot of things that take many lines}
  \end{tblr}
  \caption{With \textsf{tabularray}}
  \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Wooooow, I'm really amazed by the amount of customizations possible to achieve the same result! Each method probably has their respective pros and cons, but it's about analyzing and realizing which method fulfills your needs easily and most efficiently, I assume. Thanks for also teaching me that you can detach one row from another by using hline twice - There's so much to learn! Do you know any good resources to learn LaTeX from? I'm currently watching the "LaTeX Tutorials" serial on YT by Dr. Trefor Bazett, but I've found it lacking coverage on some troubles one could experience.

@Atex I through the double \hline was in your original code (probably a copy-paste issue). In fact, beautiful tables need few lines: take a look at the booktabs manual and at egreg alternative layout (which use booktabs). A discussion about latex resources can be found here. The classics are the books which are cited in the question. You can also look at https://www.learnlatex.org/ which is available for many languages. Anyway, technical skills comes when facing issues.

Tyvm for you and egreg's helpfulness! It has provided me with some valuable insight towards tables and resource-searching. I think that concludes my questions for now! (I'll probbably come back here if I can't find any thread answering my future question(s) ;) )
